# How to set parallel trace files available to public on Linux?

Tags: oracle

We want to add possibilities for developers to read trace files (644 permission) on Linux. We set-up Oracle variable ***_trace_files_public*** to ***true***.

After change - trace files are available to developers - but only "main" trace files - query parts that are running in parallel generate trace files with standard (640) permission.

How we can set up db to all trace files will have 644 permission ?

Comment: do you have umask set?

Comment: well, we don't want to set default permissions for all created files - this is needed only for trace files

Comment: I know, I was asking because umask could interfere in your _trace_files_public configuration.